# Display images filed in views slideshow in node content page

Tags: nodes, media, javascript

Are there any ways to format/replace the images display in a node(e./g node/1)? I add a image field for my content type which allow multiple images, i want to display it in gallery/thumbnail/jcarousel/slideshow....

I know how to make a viewslideshow in a view, but it seems no way to do the same thing in node display (e./g node/1)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create slideshow view block.
2. In view configuration, provide contextual filter of field "Content: Nid" and then provide default value "Content ID from URL".
3. Now place this block into Content region.

Answer (score 0):

if your using a module which has a field formatter, like [owlcarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel),
you can set the field to be rendered as slide show in the field UI